# ¿Por qué un campo de mi formulario HTML no se envía al servidor?

Tags: php, html

Tengo este formulario

```
<form action="agregar.php" method="POST" onSubmit="return enviarDatos();">


    <!-- linea para usuario -->



        <label class="label">*Nombre de usuario
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Nombre de usuario"  id="usuario" class="input" />
        </label>

        <!-- linea para correo -->

    <label class="label">*Correo electronico
            <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="example12@hotmail.com"  id="correo" class="input" />
        </label>

        <!-- linea para billetera -->

    <label class="label">*Billetera
            <input type="text" name="billetera" placeholder="Billetera"  id="billetera" class="input" />
        </label>

        <!-- linea para codigo  -->

        <label class="label">*Codigo 
            <input type="text" name="referido" placeholder="codigo" id="referido" class="input" />
        </label>

        <!-- linea para  contraseña -->
        <label class="label">   *Contraseña(más de seis caracteres)
            <input type="password" name="contras" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña"  id="contras" class="input" />
        </label>


    <label class="label">   *Repetir contraseña
            <input type="password" name="repcontras" placeholder="Repita contraseña"  id="repcontras" class="input" />
        </label><br><br>


     <input type="submit"  name="registrar"  value ="Registrarme" class="submit" /> 

</form>

Y este código PHP.
<?php



/* ________________________variables llamadas del formulario de html ______________________- */


$correos = $_POST['correo'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$billetera = $_POST['billetera'];
$codi =  $_POST['referido'];
$password = $_POST['contras']; 
$rePassword = $_POST['repcontras'];

session_start();

$todo = strlen($usuario) * strlen($correos) * strlen($billetera) * strlen($password )* strlen($rePassword) ;

/*____________Para activar el repcacha_____________-*/


?>
```

Me lee todas menos la de $codi

...Me sale así:

Undefined index: referido in C:\xampp\htdocs\karlos\agregar.php on line.

Pero esta igual a todos los input.

Comment: Donde usas `$codi`? Exactamente en que linea te marca el error `Undefined index: referido in C:\xampp\htdocs\karlos\agregar.php on line.`?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que realmente no estás llamando a `$codi` si no a una variable que se llama `referido` o `$referido` debes buscarlo en la linea que te muestra el error y reemplazarlo por `$codi`

> Undefined index, aparece cuando la variable no se ha definido por lo tanto no existe

Comment: En php yo le coloque la variable con nombre diferente, pero estoy llamando con el $_POST['referido']..

Porque así guarde el nombre name en el input.

Comment: Entiendo pero te diría lo mismo nuevamente ¿podrías adjuntar la linea de código que dice que tiene el error?

Comment: No entendí.. es que mira como tengo correo igual.. en php tengo a correos y en name tengo correo y me funciona

Comment: Lo que te pide es que coloque el mensaje completo del error:
C:\xampp\htdocs\karlos\agregar.php on line. (acá falta el número de línea) y que coloques el código que se encuentre en ese número de línea.